# Is it safe to store data in the Hangfire Hash table?

Tags: c#, hangfire, hangfire-sql

How long does data in the Hash table persist for?

I am redeveloping a notification system to use Hangfire to store scheduling rules and perform the `Send`. Is it safe for me to store a client identifier in the Hash table and query later?